# What kind of data structure?

Tags: arrays, json, database, text, data-structures

Can anybody help me with this data? I don't know what it is. Look similar to JSON but it isn't. I found it in DB field and I must parse this text to get "SOME TEXT".

> a:7:{s:11:"description";a:1:{s:2:"pl";s:1286:"SOME TEXT
>   ";}s:5:"rooms";a:6:{i:1;a:3:{s:6:"amount";s:0:"";s:9:"min_price";s:0:"";s:9:"max_price";s:0:"";}i:2;a:3:{s:6:"amount";s:0:"";s:9:"min_price";s:0:"";s:9:"max_price";s:0:"";}i:3;a:3:{s:6:"amount";s:0:"";s:9:"min_price";s:0:"";s:9:"max_price";s:0:"";}i:4;a:3:{s:6:"amount";s:0:"";s:9:"min_price";s:0:"";s:9:"max_price";s:0:"";}i:5;a:3:{s:6:"amount";s:0:"";s:9:"min_price";s:0:"";s:9:"max_price";s:0:"";}i:6;a:3:{s:6:"amount";s:0:"";s:9:"min_price";s:0:"";s:9:"max_price";s:0:"";}}s:4:"info";a:1:{s:2:"pl";s:357:"SOME
>   TEXT";}s:9:"in_object";a:1:{s:2:"pl";s:663:"SOME
>   TEXT";}s:13:"accommodation";a:1:{s:2:"pl";s:0:"";}s:8:"location";a:1:{s:2:"pl";s:0:"";}s:8:"catering";a:1:{s:2:"pl";s:1105:"SOME
>   TEXT";}}

Comment: I believe this is just a random text. Not of any kind

Comment: Did try using the data on JSON formatter like http://jsoneditoronline.org/ to confirm it is not JSON

Comment: @NabinKhadka: There's nothing "random" about it. It's obviously some kind of data description format, however rare it might be.

Comment: It would be useful if you told us where you got this data. Is it from a hotel data feed? Some program you're working with? The more information you can supply, the more likely we can track down the formal format description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's obviously some structure to it. Consider:

```
a:7:{
  s:11:"description";a:1:{s:2:"pl";s:1286:"SOME TEXT";}
  s:5:"rooms";
  a:6:{
    i:1;a:3:{s:6:"amount";s:0:"";s:9:"min_price";s:0:"";s:9:"max_price";s:0:"";}
    i:2;a:3:{s:6:"amount";s:0:"";s:9:"min_price";s:0:"";s:9:"max_price";s:0:"";}
    i:3;a:3:{s:6:"amount";s:0:"";s:9:"min_price";s:0:"";s:9:"max_price";s:0:"";}
    i:4;a:3:{s:6:"amount";s:0:"";s:9:"min_price";s:0:"";s:9:"max_price";s:0:"";}
    i:5;a:3:{s:6:"amount";s:0:"";s:9:"min_price";s:0:"";s:9:"max_price";s:0:"";}
    i:6;a:3:{s:6:"amount";s:0:"";s:9:"min_price";s:0:"";s:9:"max_price";s:0:"";}
  }
  s:4:"info";a:1:{s:2:"pl";s:357:"SOME TEXT";}
  s:9:"in_object";a:1:{s:2:"pl";s:663:"SOME TEXT";}
  s:13:"accommodation";a:1:{s:2:"pl";s:0:"";}
  s:8:"location";a:1:{s:2:"pl";s:0:"";}
  s:8:"catering";a:1:{s:2:"pl";s:1105:"SOME TEXT";}
}
```

I haven't done a full analysis here, but it's clear that `s:n:"string"` is a string of `n` characters with an initial value of `"string"`.

`a:n:{....}` is apparently an array with `n` items, enclosed in `{` and `}`.

Each item in the outer array has a string followed by a value. For example, the "rooms" string is followed by the array of room rates, and the "info" string is followed by a one-element array.

It appears that the `i:x` is an integer with the initial value of `x`. Or perhaps it's an array index, although not all of the arrays have indices.

As to what the format is called, I don't know. It looks like somebody's home-grown and very narrowly targeted data description language. I wrote similar things way back before we had standard stuff like XML and JSON.

Comment: Nice analysis, it's really helped me. Thanks!